# Cannot bundle exec rake:db:rollback due to errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am fairly new to Rails, and I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

I have a teaches model in my rails app, and I want to delete this model using `rails destroy model teaches`. However, when I run `bundle exec rake db:rollback`, I keep getting this error

`Mysql2::Error: Error on rename of './CrimeEducApp_development/#sql-ca1_27' to './CrimeEducApp_development/teaches' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed): ALTER TABLE teaches DROP PRIMARY KEY;`

The teaches model doesn't have any tables that uses its attributes as foreign keys, but the teaches model does have attributes that reference from other tables.

**Model File**

```
require 'composite_primary_keys'

class Teach < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :course_id, :certification_number
  belongs_to :course, class_name: "Course", foreign_key: "course_id"
  belongs_to :worker, class_name: "Worker", foreign_key: "certification_number"
end
```

**Migration File**

```
class CreateTeaches < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    create_table :teaches , {:id => false} do |t|
      t.integer :course_id
      t.integer :certification_number

      t.timestamps
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE teaches ADD PRIMARY KEY(course_id, certification_number);"
    execute "ALTER TABLE teaches ADD CONSTRAINT teaches_references_course FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES courses(course_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;"
    execute "ALTER TABLE teaches ADD CONSTRAINT teaches_references_worker FOREIGN KEY (certification_number) REFERENCES workers(certification_number) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;"
  end

  def down
    execute "ALTER TABLE teaches DROP PRIMARY KEY;"
    execute "ALTER TABLE teaches DROP FOREIGN KEY teaches_references_course;"
    execute "ALTER TABLE teaches DROP FOREIGN KEY teaches_references_worker;"
    drop_table :teaches
  end
end
```

Is it possible that I am referencing my attributes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, dropping the primary keys have to be after, if not, the last execute statement.